# Fastest way to perform math on section of 2D array (less for loops)?

Tags: c++, arrays, performance, math, slice

I am currently translating my code from Python into C++, which I am new to. In the script, a droplet of water, whose x-y position is represented by a 2-element array of floats pos[], needs to alter nearby points on a 2d array heightmap[][]. This heightmap stores one "height" value between 0 and 1 at each pair of indices (one for x, one for y). The goal is that the droplet will affect the points on the heightmap within a certain constant radius, which means the distance to each nearby point must be calculated. The change in height of each point will also be weighted by the inverse of the distance, as well as the sum of all valid distances to ensure uniform distribution.

The trouble is performance, as this requires many for loops. Two pairs of nested loops, each of which must execute many steps depending on the radius constant. This whole function will be called up to 40 times per "droplet" and the simulation uses literally tens of thousands of said droplets. The performance overall isn't terrible, but I feel as though there is a much simpler solution that I am unaware of, either in the way the heightmap is represented (is a 2d array like this the best way to go?) or how it is referenced. Nothing I found while searching seemed useful. Any help is appreciated!

```
void erode(float pos[], float deltaSediment) {
    int x = floor(pos[0]);
    int y = floor(pos[1]);
    float brush[2 * radius][2 * radius];
    float sum = 0;
    float dist = 0;
    for (int u = 1; u < 2*radius; u++) {
        for (int v = 1; v < 2*radius; v++) {
            dist = distance(u + x - radius, v + y - radius, pos[0], pos[1]);
            if (dist <= radius) {
                brush[u][v] = 1/distance(u + x - radius, v + y - radius, pos[0], pos[1]);
                sum += dist;
            }
            else {
                brush[u][v] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int u = 1; u < 2*radius; u++) {
        for (int v = 1; v < 2*radius; v++) {
            heightmap[u + x - radius][v + y - radius] -= deltaSediment * brush[u][v] / sum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not a solution, but compiling with something like -0fast or -03 will likely improve performance. Otherwise, its hard to tell a program to run faster without some change in implementation

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'll check that out.

Comment: Just curious, why are you calling the function 40 times per droplet?

Comment: @RixYarbrough `float brush[2 * radius][2 * radius];` -- What type is `radius`?  If it is not a constant, that line of code is not legal C++.

Comment: One thing to note, you called `distance(u + x - radius, v + y - radius, pos[0], pos[1])` twice. You should probably use `dist` for the second call, since you already stored the result.

Comment: @Jaan It's a simulation of Hydraulic erosion. Each step the droplet changes its position to move downhill depending on the gradient of the heightmap. At each position, it will run this function to "erode" the height values.

Comment: Instead of `distance` use C math function [**`hypot`**](https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/library-function/math.h/hypot). (Though doubles)

Comment: @Ranoiaetep Yeah I realized that a minute ago and changed it to use dist instead. Also, the radius is a constant int defined elsewhere.

Comment: @RixYarbrough If it's constant, what is the value of `radius`?  Local 2D arrays can blow out the stack memory depending on the size of the array.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I am aware. The value of radius is only 3. This script runs fine but I am interested to know better etiquette regarding doing these sorts of things with arrays. I spent a long time in python doing things wrong and it killed performance. Also, the heightmap is 256x256 but is defined outside of any function so it does not overflow.

Comment: I think you are using those nested loops to search for neighbors around your point of interest.  You can bypass all of that by using binary space partitioning.  Google terms like BSP, KD tree and Quad tree.

Comment: `float brush[2 * radius][2 * radius];` --> `float brush[2 * radius][2 * radius] = {}`.  Then that `else` part of the `for` loop where you are setting `brush[u][v]` to 0 can be eliminated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good tip. Thanks!

Comment: You should profile the code to see, where performance can possibly be improved. It might be different from what you think.

Comment: @infinitezero Thanks for the advice! New to this, so didn't think of that at all.

Comment: @RixYarbrough -- But if radius is only 3, this function should have ran in almost no time.  A 2D array is in contiguous memory, so cache misses should not be an issue.  If radius was a million, then there would be concern due to multiple issues.  1) The number of points, of course.  2) How the 2D is implemented (a 1D array off the heap, or an "array of arrays", heap-based but slower).  Given radius is only 3, this function if you look at it as isolated, IMO, is not a concern.

Comment: Do you expect a perfect alignment `(pos[i] == (floor)pos[i])` to cause `1/dist == inf`? (Also shouldn't the sum be computed over 1/dist)? In any case I would just compute the 6x6 grid using SIMD intrinsics (if -O3 doesn't do it). I don't see any short cuts. Even a LUT will grow way too large (say `float lut[16][16][36]` is 36kb) with `pos[i] - (floor)pos[i]` quantized to only 16 elements.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen You are right, I might need to revise the math on that! I wasn't thinking clearly when I wrote it in python I think. It also would likely never equal zero as I was dealing with numbers of much greater precision, but very close to zero would be possible and an issue. That never occurred to me. Also yes, I noticed the sum was wrong and fixed that too. Thanks so much for the tips!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, it is actually very fast. I was curious as a beginner if there was a more elegant way to write this, as there was in Python, using a library. Using so many for loops like this just feels clunky. Looking back, that library probably just did exactly this, but in C, so it was faster. This script WAS acting slower than I expected, but it was for other issues people noted. The dist variable and not using hypot were slowing things quite a bit.